# how to make the text in the middle

Tags: css

i have following code i want the text in the div to come in the middle .
i know this is very easy question but i am getting problem in these type of questins please suggest me the what can i do to solve these kind of problems in future.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
.transition-msg {
background-color:#000000;
font-size:20px;
height:624px;
color:#fff;
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
top:6%;
width:1014px;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: block;" class="transition-msg" id="transition-msg">Entering rahuls Gib</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it look like, where is the problem? Also, why `position: absolute`? That strikes me as odd.

Comment: i cant remove the position absolute because i want this at particular positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div style="display: block;" class="transition-msg" id="transition-msg"><div class="transition-msg1">Entering rahuls Gib
    </div>

.transition-msg-text{
background-color:#000000;
font-size:20px;
height:624px;
color:#fff;
display:table-cell;
margin:0 auto;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
width:1014px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute;` and it should work just as you want it to.

Comment: i cant remove the position absolute because i want this at particular positions

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.transition-msg{
width:1014px;
height:600px;
background-color:#000000;
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
font-size:20px;
left:15%;
text-align:center;
top:6%;
}
</style>
```

You can achieve this by removing position absolute.

Comment: no sorry for position:absolute; the margin:auto not working so you can do this by changing ur css rules.